# Nest text inside SVG path

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to nest text (like a `text` element) inside an SVG `path` element?

I am asking because I would like a text balloon to show up when hovering over a path, something like this:

```
path#mypath:hover text {
    display:block;
}
```

I would like to avoid using JavaScript, but I understand that may be the only option.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yes you can use `<text>` inside `<svg>`.

You can use:

```
svg text:hover{
    fill:red;
}
```

To apply css rules when hovered. Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Fhc/). But if you want to display a bubble notification that changes position based on hovered element, you must use JavaScript. If the position does not change then you can do it in CSS by simply hiding and displaying a div.

Comment: Nesting _<text>_ directly inside _<svg>_ is valid. However nesting inside _<path>_ is not.

Answer (score 10):

According to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path your can not nest `<text>` inside `<path>`

You could however use an adjacent element as the trigger for the hover effect: http://jsfiddle.net/93ufH/1/

```
<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
    <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue" > 
        Hello
    </text>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
svg text{
    visibility:hidden;
}

svg rect:hover + text{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: @Sigma Yes you can put `<text>` inside a `<svg>` but not inside a `<path` which is what the OP wants to do

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display tooltip, You can insert title element into target shape element, like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50">
        <title>tooltip</title>
    </circle>
</svg>
```